# A WordPress Plugin button that pops-up the rest of the form

Tags: php, wordpress

I started with developing WordPress plugins today and was creating this custom plugin when I faced this issue.
I have form in the `function html_form_code()`
Now I want the plugin to initially display a button called 'Request Details' which on click will show the form.

I tried creating a function that has a button 'Request Details' and
call the `html_form_code()` function from it like this:

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="button" value="Request Details">';
if(isset($_POST['button']) 
    //call the function html_form_code()
```

Although this displayed the button correctly it did not display the rest of the form on click.

Here's the `html_form_code()`function:

```
function html_form_code() {
    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Email <br/>';
    echo '<input type="email" name="cf-email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Phone Number<br/>';
    echo '<input type="number" name="cf-number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-number"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-number"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Group Size<br/>';
    echo '<input type="number" name="cf-size" pattern="[0-9]{2}" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-size"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-size"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Date<br/>';
    echo '<input type="date" name="cf-date" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-date"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-date"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Here's the function calling the above

```
function cf_shortcode() {

    ob_start();
    deliver_mail();
    html_form_code();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

`deliver_mail()` is another funnction that works after the submit button is clicked.
Any possible solution on how to do this or where to include the button would be appreciated.

Comment: We need to see some more code to help out. What you posted isn't nearly enough to understand what's going on. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more.

Comment: Added, almost my entire plugin. check.

Comment: You could use some CSS & JS to: 1. keep the form initially hidden from view, and 2. handle clicks on your "Request details" to toggle the visibility of the form.

Comment: Could you suggest me a link/tutorial how to include a custom css to the plugin?

Comment: Sure: [Plugin Handbook | WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/).